Flutter ML Kit Face Detection: Video Recording Only Triggers on First Face Detection
I'm implementing face detection with Google ML Kit in a Flutter app to start and stop video recording each time a face is detected. However, I’m running into a bug where the video recording only starts on the first detection. Further detections don’t trigger any additional recordings.
My _processCameraImage function initializes recording on face detection, using a flag (_isProcessingImage) to ensure only one image frame is processed at a time. After the initial recording, though, it stops detecting faces due to how the _isProcessingImage flag and asynchronous logic interact.
I tried resetting the _isProcessingImage flag at the end of _processCameraImage to allow further detections, and I ensured _startRecording only activates when no current recording is running. Despite these changes, subsequent recordings don't start after the first one finishes. How can I fix this so it repeatedly detects faces and starts recording for each new detection?
Future<void> _processCameraImage(CameraImage image) async {
    if (_isProcessingImage) return;
    _isProcessingImage = true;
    try {
      logger.i('reached');
      final WriteBuffer allBytes = WriteBuffer();
      for (Plane plane in image.planes) {
        allBytes.putUint8List(plane.bytes);
      }
      final bytes = allBytes.done().buffer.asUint8List();

      final inputImage = InputImage.fromBytes(
        bytes: bytes,
        metadata: InputImageMetadata(
          size: Size(image.width.toDouble(), image.height.toDouble()),
          rotation: InputImageRotation.rotation0deg,
          format: Platform.isAndroid
              ? InputImageFormat.nv21
              : InputImageFormat.yuv420,
          bytesPerRow: image.planes[0].bytesPerRow,
        ),
      );

      final faces = await _faceDetector.processImage(inputImage);
      if (faces.isNotEmpty &&
          !widget.cameraController.value.isRecordingVideo &&
          _minutes > 0) {
        _startRecording();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      logger.e("Error processing image: $e");
    } finally {
      _isProcessingImage = false;
    }
  }

